# Ubuntu 19.04 Hotspot is not visible to android phones

Tags: hot-spot

I created a wifi hotspot on my ubuntu Laptop, but when I search for it on my android phone it's not visible. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you see it with any other devices?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on an upgraded machine which worked fine in 18.04...google found no answer, so decided to go back to basics. Looked in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot` ... lo and behold buried in the `[Wifi]` section was a line:

```
Hidden=true
```

Change it to `Hidden=false` and bingo the hotspot became visible to all android and iOS devices instantly.

Comment: sorry, but it did not work here...  the mentioned line was not there... anyway, I inserted it and it does not work :-(